# Application removes itself from "login items"

Tags: macos, mac, applications, login-items

Probably an *opposite* issue compared to what people post in here. I have a simple menu bar app hider, [Vanilla](https://matthewpalmer.net/vanilla/), in free version. A "pro" feature is to make it start at login, which can be done from `Users and groups`>`Login items`. However, this app seemingly removes itself from this list upon restart.

Can this behavior be changed? I feel like it's fairly intrusive that applications can manipulate this list on my behalf.

**EDIT**:
To elaborate, this is not about *not* wanting to support developers which I do all the time being one myself. This is more about questioning malware-like behavior of software that, without your permission whatsoever, can modify OS-level settings.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can change it by buying the Pro version of Matthew Palmer's [Vanilla](https://matthewpalmer.net/vanilla/) which will allow you to permanently add the app to the Login Items list.

If you really do not want to give 4.99$ to a guy giving out free software that he spends his own time making, you could startup the app using launchd or similar that doesn't use Login Items. Or you use a similar method to re-add it to Login Items when it is removed.

Comment: Comments should be used for clarifications, not for general discussions about the  merits of an answer (or question). Please use chat for general discussions.